# Consulta de categoria no MySQL

Tags: mysql, inner

Estou aprendendo MySQL, preciso de uma ajuda,  preciso efetuar uma consulta que me retorne uma lista de vendas pela categoria do produto.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
tb categoria 
campos: (id, categoria) 
dados: (12, camisas)
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
tb produto 
campos: (id, categoria_id, nome produto)
dados: (1 , 12, camisas leves)
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
tb compra 
campos: (id, produto_id, id_vendedor) 
dados: (5, 1, 23)

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Na tb compra preciso listar as vendas pela categoria através do  "id do produto" pelo operador

Vocês podem me ajudar, por gentileza?

Comment: edita a pergunta e coloca parte do seu projeto sua *conexao* e *variaveis*

Comment: Na tabela categoria qual é o tipo de dado ? int ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos lá, se entendi direito sua pergunta você precisa fazer uma consulta que retorne **vendas** a partir de uma determinada **categoria**.

Ocorre que **categoria não está presente na tabela de vendas**, não é mesmo?

Como resolver isso?

A **venda** possui um **produto**, e este sim possui uma **categoria**. Então utilizamos o **relacionamento entre as tabelas**, através do conceito que chamamos de **chave estrangeira (FK - *Foreign Key*)**, para obter a informação desejada. Fazemos isso através de operações de **JOIN** (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Segue um exemplo de `SELECT` pra ilustrar (baseado nos campos que você passou).

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM tb_compra c
 INNER JOIN tb_produto p ON p.id = c.produto_id
 INNER JOIN tb_categoria ct ON ct.id = p.categoria_id
 WHERE ct.id = 12;
```

Comment: Fico grato, agradeço por sua disposição em ajudar, deu tudo certo.